# MariaDb composite partitioning

Tags: mariadb

I need to create a composite partitionning in Mariadb range/list, in Oracle the command is:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id Integer, 
    pdateid Integer )
TABLESPACE tbs_t1
PARTITION BY RANGE (pdateid)
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (id)
    SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
    (
         SUBPARTITION SP1 VALUES (1,2), 
         SUBPARTITION SPDEF VALUES (DEFAULT)
    )
(
    PARTITION APR_2015 VALUES LESS THAN (3043) tablespace tbs_t1_APR, 
    PARTITION MAY_2015 VALUES LESS THAN (3074) tablespace tbs_t1_MAY
) ;
```

1-what could be the syntax for the same command in MariaDb ,and how to specify the storage for the partitions (ex: tbs_t1_APR)?
2-which storage engine should be choosen in this case for best performance?
3-which command give the template of the partiton?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Executive Summary:  Forget Oracle syntax; hit the books on MySQL/MariaDB syntax.  There are *many* differences.

Details:

`NUMBER(*,0)` -- Perhaps you want `INT`?

`3043` is not a valid value for the datatype `DATE`; `'2016-03-08'` is.

`SUBPARTITIONs` are useless for performance; forget about them.

"Tablespaces" are virtually useless in MySQL/MariaDB; don't bother with them.

`PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(partid))` *may* be useful to you.  Will you have at least a million rows?  Will you be dropping "old" data?  Can you use about 20-60 partitions?

If you are looking for other things in partitioning; forget it.  It's probably not worth pursuing.

Let's see the `SELECTs` you will hit the table with.  (This may give some clues about where to take the discussion.)

Comment: Hi James, it's an Id date( number of day from a reference date -say 01/01/2006).Yes it's a big table and need to purge the old data. need to formulate the same command in MySql/Mariadb,already have the partitioning under an Oracle database .thanks

Comment: My advice for purging old data: [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: `INTEGER` == `INT` -- 4-byte number -2 billion to +2 billion.  Is that sufficient?